# Pass object through router-outlet ng2

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I make `items` object taken from `app-component (root)` work in commented `router-outlet`?

```html
<div class="header">
  <app-header></app-header>
  <app-navbar [items]="items"></app-navbar>
</div>

<div class="container" >
  <router-outlet></router-outlet> <!-- <router-outlet [items]="items"></router-outlet> doesn't work-->
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Comment: You can't. Use a shared service to communicate with components added by the router https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: Oh well.. Thanks for that info.